# При использовании Webpack перестают работать методы для onChange

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, onchange

Есть примерно такой код:

```
<select id="selectValue1" onChange="getStaticInfo('#selectValue1')">
<option selected value="Выберите значение">Выберите значение</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="selectValue2" onChange="getStaticInfo('#selectValue2')">
<option selected value="Выберите значение">Выберите значение</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label><input name="dens" type="radio" value="auto" onchange="getRadioChecked()">Автоматический</label>
<label><input name="dens" type="radio" value="handle" onchange="getRadioChecked()">Ручной</label>

<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

// JS

```
    function getStaticInfo(selector) {
const transmitter = document.querySelector(selector)

transmitter.addEventListener('change', () => {
    switch (transmitter.getAttribute('id')) {
        case 'selectValue1':
            levelTransmitter = transmitter.value
            someFunction1()
            break
        case 'selectValue2':
            tempTransmitter = transmitter.value
            someFunction2()
            break
    }
})


function getRadioChecked() {
let densRadio = document.getElementsByName('dens')

densRadio.forEach((elem) => {
    //some code
})
```

В таком виде всё работает, ошибок в консоли браузера нет. Но если применить webpack (npx webpack), и в `index.html` изменить путь к js-файлу на `dist/main.js`, то в консоли браузера получаем:

[image: Ошибка в консоли браузера]

Но (!) функции внутри getStaticInfo выполняются и value из select-списка уходит куда надо, а вот радио кнопка не работает.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Проблему удалось решить. Для этого пришлось отказаться от использования удобного атрибута событий onChange непосредственно в html.

Функция обработки события выбора элемента списка осталась без изменений, так что просто удаляем атрибут onChange из html-кода.

А вот для обработки события выбора радио-кнопки (и, как выяснилось, для checkbox тоже) необходимо обернуть input в form.
Верста будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<form class="form">
<label><input name="dens" type="radio" value="auto">Автоматический</label>
<label><input name="dens" type="radio" value="handle">Ручной</label>
</form>

<form class="anotherForm">
<label><input class="input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Текст</label>
</form>
```

Функция обработки события выбора радио-кнопки:

```
function getRadioChecked() {
    const form = document.querySelector('.form')
    const densRadio = document.getElementsByName('dens')

    form.addEventListener('change', () => {
        densRadio.forEach(elem => {
            if (elem.checked && elem.value === 'auto') {
                // some code
            }
            if (elem.checked && elem.value === 'handle') {
                // some code
            }
        })
    })
}
getRadioChecked()
```

Функция обработки события установки галочки (checkbox):

```
function getChecked() {
const anotherForm = document.querySelector('.anotherForm')
const chbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox')
anotherForm.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (chbox.checked) {
        //some code
    } else {
        // some code
    }
  })
}
getChecked()
```

Всё это довольно просто, но при поиске информации про обработку подобных событий почти все примеры с использованием атрибута onChange.

Также выяснилось, что Webpack скорее всего был не причем. Например, если без использования Webpack поместить весь javascript-код внутрь конструкции

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// all code
})
```

то функции, переданные в атрибут onChange также перестанут работать (станут is not defined). Вероятно, проблема из области Event loop или контекста вызова, пока не разобрался.